Does expo-local-authentication need expo package for bare react native 0.66 project
Does expo-local-authentication need expo package for bare react native 0.66 project as react-native-unimodule is deprecated for gradle 7
What extra configuration needed for iOS and Android to make expo-local-authentication work.
I tried installing following packages but its not working and no error
"expo-local-authentication": "^12.1.1",
"expo-modules-core": "^0.6.5",
